# Merging sqlite tables into single datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

So I had 3 sqlite tables named abc, t2, and t3. I wanted to merge all three of them into one datagrid. By this I mean, first abc comes, then below it should be t2, then below that t3.

This was my original code for showing only table abc in the datagrid view:

```
 string sql = " SELECT * FROM abc";
       SQLiteDataAdapter da;
       DataTable dt;

       sqlite_cmd.CommandText = sql;

       //Create New Datatable to fill with data
       dt = new DataTable();

       //Create DataAdapter to fill data in DataTable via Adapter
       da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, sqlite_conn);
       da.Fill(dt);

       // Lets populate the datagrid
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
       dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

---

The code below is what a user suggested I should use to merge all 3 tables into 1 datagrid view. Given my lack of programming knowledge, I didn't know how to synchronize his answer with my code above. **The error I was getting from his code is that the name 'abc', 't2', and 't3' don't exist in the current context.(most likely because they dont have any sqlite statements a**

---

The goal here is to merge 3 tables into 1 data grid view. The error above is preventing me from doing so. An answer in full code would be appreciated.

```
DataTable allDTs = abc;
       int rowCount = allDTs.Rows.Count - 1;
       foreach (DataRow row in t2.Rows)
       {
           rowCount = rowCount + 1;
           allDTs.Rows.Add();

           int colCount = -1;
           foreach (DataColumn col in t2.Columns)
           {
               colCount = colCount + 1;
               if (colCount > allDTs.Columns.Count - 1) allDTs.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
               allDTs.Rows[rowCount][colCount] = row[col];
           }
       }

       rowCount = allDTs.Rows.Count - 1;
       foreach (DataRow row in t3.Rows)
       {
           rowCount = rowCount + 1;
           allDTs.Rows.Add();

           int colCount = -1;
           foreach (DataColumn col in t3.Columns)
           {
               colCount = colCount + 1;
               if (colCount > allDTs.Columns.Count - 1) allDTs.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
               allDTs.Rows[rowCount][colCount] = row[col];
           }
       }

       dataGridView1.DataSource = allDTs;
```

Comment: (you can ask this in the previous question) My code expects three tables containing data (abc, t2 and t3). Declare each table and perform the corresponding query (da = new SQLiteDataAdapter etc. for each table) to populate them from the DB and then write my code. Actually, I thought that the DataTables were already populated; you might come up with a single SQL query to store the data from the three tables in one go.

Comment: @varocarbas (just didn't want to annoy you) Thanks for your help! How do I exactly perform da = new SQLiteDataAdapter for each table? Like this? da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(SELECT * FROM abc, sqlite_conn) ?

Comment: (annoy me?! why? I am kind of passionate but pretty un-annoyable! Did I say anything wrong in the previous question?) If this query works fine and this is exactly what you want to do, yes.

Comment: Also, do I need to create new data adapter variables for each table

Comment: No. As said, just emulate the code which works with all the tables.

Comment: Shucks, it's still not functioning properly. I tried your method but am still getting the same error I bolded above. The code is pretty long so I cant paste it here. Can I please get help from you on email?THANKS! @varocarbas

Comment: This error appears when you are not declaring the given objects (dt, t2 and t3), so you are doing something wrong. Please, post your whole code, such that I can see where is the problem. Sorry, but one thing is helping you here a bit and other thing is providing custom support for free (still not there :)). Please, post all the code you wrote either here or via a web like pastebin.com

Comment: Hey, no problem at all: here's my code :) : http://pastebin.com/e7iifKSg

Comment: Test this one: http://pastebin.com/EUjeKBZg

Comment: Works like a charm, the comments are very helpful. You should post that link as an answer so I can accept it and give you points

Comment: I don't care about points; just about fairness (and doing what is good for SO). This question and my answer, purely speaking, don't belong here (will not be helpful to others), so what would be the point? I am happy to have helped you, but bear in mind that this is not how SO is expected to be used. Feel free to delete this question if you wish.

Comment: @varocarbas Hi, how would I merge only able t2 and t3 and not abc. Basically I want a new table with only containing t2 and t3, abc doesn't need to be dealt with D: would I have to do a Select from *t2 and t3 first

Comment: I think that have provided a custom-enough help (this is not what SO is about). Try to learn from my help, do things by your own and, please, don't make me regret having helped you.